# Node + Docker Compose: Development and production setup

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, development-environment, production-environment

I'm looking for a solution to have both a **development** and a **production** environment in my project using docker, docker-compose and nodejs.

How do I approach this?

Basically what I want is a **command to start my docker production environment**, and a **command to start my development environment** (which could use nodemon for example).

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:13-alpine

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 1234

CMD ["npm", "run", "prod"] # <--- Have a possibility to run something like "npm run dev" here instead
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
    findus:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "1234:1234"
        links:
            - mongo
        container_name: myapp
    mongo:
        image: mongo
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "4444:4444"
```

package.json

```
// ...
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tsc",
        "dev": "nodemon source/index.ts",
        "prod": "node build/index.js"
    },
// ...
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can make use of entrypoint and pass the command to the docker container. Then you can use docker-compose inharitance to launch compose for the environment that you want and append command to the entrypoint.

**Dockerfile** :

```
FROM node:13-alpine

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 1234

ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run"]
```

Main **docker-compose.yml** :

```
version: "3"
services:
    findus:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "1234:1234"
        links:
            - mongo
        container_name: myapp
    mongo:
        image: mongo
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "4444:4444"
```

And then have two docker-compose files to append the command passed to the image entry point. For development - **docker-compose.dev.yml** :

```
version: "3"
services:
    findus:
        command: dev
```

and **docker-compose.prod.yml** :

```
version: "3"
services:
    findus:
        command: prod
```

Then to launch dev environment :

```
docker-compose  -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up
```

and for prod environment :

```
docker-compose  -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up
```

So the `command` will be appended to the `ENTRYPOINT` instruction.

---

Also this approach could work with enviroment variables if you wanted to pass the command as environment variable. You can find more information in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/).

Comment: is this approach gonna watch for file changes on `dev` environment ?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to create two "targets" on your Dockerfile like this:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:13-alpine As development

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM node:13-alpine as production

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --only=production

COPY . .

COPY --from=development /app/dist ./dist

CMD ["node", "dist/index.js"]
```

And them on your docker-compose run only the Development version:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  main:
    container_name: main
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
    command: npm run dev
...
```

So on your dev environment, you can run:

> docker-compose up

and them in prod you can run docker directly with

> docker run --target production

I'm assuming that when you run "npm run build" you are generating a dist/production folder so it's better to run node there instead of running straight at index.js on your root folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a structure like this:

> ```
> docker-compose.yml -->
>       docker-compose.dev.yml
>       docker-compose.prod.yml
> ```

Where the base configuration resides in `docker-compose.yml`, while environment-specific info such as ports or user credentials would be in `docker-compose.dev.yml` or `docker-compose.prod.yml`

And then you can run the dev environment with:

```
docker-compose \
    -f docker-compose.yml \
    -f docker-compose.dev.yml \
    up -d
```

Or the prod environment with:

```
docker-compose \
    -f docker-compose.yml \
    -f docker-compose.prod.yml \
    up -d
```